# AttributeError: module 'open3d' has no attribute 'registration'

Tags: python, import, documentation, open3d

When trying to follow [the documentation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.9.0/python_api/open3d.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint.html) to use `open3d.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint`, getting

> AttributeError: module 'open3d' has no attribute 'registration'

How to use `TransformationEstimationPointToPoint`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long long search, I found [this](https://github.com/fabiopoiesi/dip/issues/5) on Github.

The documentation is obsolete.

Instead of

```
open3d.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint
```

use

```
open3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint
```